# Returning value from nested completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I have a completion block which takes a parameter which is dynamic based on the user selection something like this :

```
NSString *data = <some value based on user selection>;
[avc activity:data withBlock:^id _Nonnull{

}
```

This block has return type as id.

I have another block something like this :

```
[self createItem:data completion:^(NSString * _Nullable item) {
    //value of item is received here
}];
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
NSString *data = <some value based on user selection>;
//This data is used in both the blocks
[avc activity:data withBlock:^id _Nonnull{
    [self createItem:data completion:^(NSString * _Nullable item) {
        return item; //Error here
    }];
}
```

Returning the item throws error because the return type of inner block is void. What I want to achieve is when the inner block received the value in item it should return it to the outer block.

I tried using dispatch group like this:

```
NSString *data = <some value based on user selection>;
//This data is used in both the blocks
[avc activity:data withBlock:^id _Nonnull{
    __block NSString *url = nil;
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [self createItem:data completion:^(NSString * _Nullable item) {
        url = item;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return url
}
```

This does not work. The app gets indefinitely stuck after the wait statement.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: try creating a block with parameter,:(void (^)(id item))block, and instead of return item, just call block(item)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri outer block is a library function so can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock:^{
  NSString *data; // <some value based on user selection>;
  [avc activity:data withBlock:^id _Nonnull{
      __block NSString *url = nil;
      dispatch_semaphore_t finished = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self createItem:data completion:^(NSString * _Nullable item) {
            url = item;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(finished);
        }];
      }];
      dispatch_semaphore_wait(finished, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
      return url
  }];
}];
```